# Cell count distribution assumption in loglinear modelling

Tags: poisson-distribution, multinomial-distribution, log-linear

In relation to loglinear analysis, SPSS gives two options for "Distribution of Cell Counts". The SPSS User Manual states:

> **Assumptions.**    Two distributions are available in General Loglinear Analysis: Poisson and multinomial.
>
> Under the Poisson distribution assumption:
>   - The total sample size is not fixed before the study, or the analysis is not conditional on the total sample size.
>   - The event of an observation being in a cell is statistically independent of the cell counts of other cells.
>
> Under the multinomial distribution assumption:
>   - The total sample size is fixed, or the analysis is conditional on the total sample size.
>   - The cell counts are not statistically independent.

I find this confusing. I understand that the Poisson distribution is the distribution of the number of events in a given time (or area, distance, volume, etc) if those events are occurring independently, and the probability that an event occurs does not change through time. For example: What is the probability there will be 4 car accidents on a university campus in a given week?

I understand that the multinomial distribution is a generalization of the binomial distribution, whereby the number of possible outcomes can be greater than two. For example: If we randomly sample 10 people, what are the chances 4 are blood type A, 2 are type AB, 3 are type B, and 1 is type O?

I don't see how this relates to the sample size issue mentioned in the SPSS User Manual. I also don't know what I'm supposed to do if I think that cell counts are statistically independent but the sample size is fixed, or if the cell counts are not statistically independent but the sample size was not fixed.

Comment: Imagine cars come in red, blue and "other". If I set out to observe 10 cars, and I observe 5 red, I *cannot* observe more than 5 blue. On the other hand, if I set out to observe cars for ten minutes and I observe 5 red, I can certainly observe more than 5 blue.

Comment: This comment has helped me see the link between Poisson and independent cell counts, and Multinomial and a lack of independent cell counts. If I fix the sample size before the study, are the cell counts by definition not statistically independent?

Comment: That's right, they're dependent. Let's consider $n$ observations on $k$ categories with probabilities $p_1,p_2,...,p_k$. Let the cell counts be $X_1,X_2,...,X_k$. If $i\neq j$, $\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j)=-np_ip_j$. This can be shown quite easily.